# Duplicating Data in MVC and Datatables

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a system that creates report for monthly sales. The approach that's been made is that  create a stored procedure for data, then display it using JSON.

To implement this, I wrote this SP

```
SELECT distinct
C.type as "CAMPAIGN TYPE",
'' as "MUST BUY",
'' as "RFB NUMBER",
AE.firstname + ' ' + AE.lastname as "ASSIGNED AE",
AG.name_1 + ' ' + AG.name_2 as "AGENCY",
AD.name_1 + ' ' + AD.name_2 as "ADVERTISER",
P.name as "PRODUCT",
MH.campaign as "CAMPAIGN",
MH.document_date as "BO/TO DATE",
'' as "BG DATE",
MH.document_number as "DOCUMENT NUMBER",
MH.created AS "IO DATE",
RIGHT('00000000'+CAST(MH.id AS VARCHAR(8)),8) as "IO NUMBER",
--MD.flight_date_start as "START DATE",
--MD.flight_date_end as "END DATE",

left(MD.multi_dates,10) as "START DATE",
RIGHT(MD.multi_dates,10) as "END DATE",
--SS.firstname + ' ' + SS.lastname as "SD",
Md.id as "ID",
    [1] AS Jan,
    [2] AS Feb,
    [3] AS Mar,
    [4] AS Apr,
    [5] AS May,
    [6] AS Jun,
    [7] AS Jul,
    [8] AS Aug,
    [9] AS Sep,
    [10] AS Oct,
    [11] AS Nov,
    [12] AS Dec
FROM
    (SELECT [moh_id]
    ,MONTH(date) as TMonth  
    ,[mod_id]
    ,[status]
    ,[billcost]
    ,[intcost]
  FROM flight_dates WHERE Year(date) = Year(getdate())) source
  PIVOT
(
    SUM(intcost)
    FOR TMonth
    IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )
) 

AS F join media_headers MH on (F.moh_id = MH.id and MH.confirmed = 1) 
  join media_details MD on (F.mod_id = MD.id)
  left outer join flight FD on (MH.id = FD.mod_id)
  full outer join services S on (MD.service_id = S.id)
  full outer join campaign C on (C.id = S.template_type)
  full outer join executives AE on (MH.account_executive_id = AE.id)
  full outer join ae_sd_vp SD on (ae.id = SD.ae_id)
  full outer join executives SS on (SD.sd_id = SS.id)
  full outer join products P on (P.id = MH.product_id)
join agency_advertisers AG on (MH.agency_id = AG.sap_agen_code)
join agency_advertisers AD on (MH.advertiser_id = AD.adv_code)
order by C.type2
```

The flight tables holds the sales per day. I call this SP using my API

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMonthlySalesReport()
{     
var rpt = await _context.MonthlySalesReport.FromSql(@"MonthlySalesReport").ToListAsync();   
    return Json(rpt);
}
```

Then return it to my `cshtlm` file using ajax and use DataTables to catch the data.

```
  ajax: {
                        dataSrc: '',
                        url: '../api/order/Order/GetMonthlySalesReport'
                    },
```

The Class for MonthlySalesReport is this:

```
public class MonthlySalesReport
    {   
        //[Column("ID"), Key]
        //public int ID { get; set; }
        [Column("CAMPAIGN TYPE"), Key]
        public string CampaignType{ get; set; }
        [Column("MUST BUY")]
        public string MustBuy { get; set; }
        [Column("RFB NUMBER")]
        public string RFBNumber { get; set; }
        [Column("ASSIGNED AE")]
        public string AssignedAE { get; set; }
        [Column("AGENCY")]
        public string Agency { get; set; }
        [Column("ADVERTISER")]
        public string Advertiser { get; set; }
        [Column("PRODUCT")]
        public string Product { get; set; }
        [Column("CAMPAIGN")]
        public string Campaign { get; set; }
        [Column("BO/TO DATE")]
        public DateTime? BODate { get; set; }
        [Column("BG DATE")]
        public string BGDate { get; set; }
        [Column("DOCUMENT NUMBER")]
        public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
        [Column("IO DATE")]
        public DateTime? IODate { get; set; }
        [Column("IO NUMBER")]
        public string IONumber { get; set; }
        [Column("START DATE")]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        [Column("END DATE")]
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        //[Column("SD")]
        //public string SD { get; set; }
        [Column("JAN")]
        public Decimal? January { get; set; }
        [Column("FEB")]
        public Decimal? February { get; set; }
        [Column("MAR")]
        public Decimal? March { get; set; }
        [Column("APR")]
        public Decimal? April { get; set; }
        [Column("MAY")]
        public Decimal? May { get; set; }
        [Column("JUN")]
        public Decimal? June { get; set; }
        [Column("JUL")]
        public Decimal? July { get; set; }
        [Column("AUG")]
        public Decimal? August { get; set; }
        [Column("SEP")]
        public Decimal? September { get; set; }
        [Column("OCT")]
        public Decimal? October { get; set; }
        [Column("NOV")]
        public Decimal? November { get; set; }
        [Column("DEC")]
        public Decimal? Decmber { get; set; }

    }
```

My problem now is that, the MVC application is producing different and duplicated data in compare with data that is produced by SQL. How's that even possible?

Any tips or help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are convinced that the data from the proc is not being reflected in the view then the next logical point if investigation is the JSON being sent to the view. But you need to be absolutely certain the proc is producing what you think it is. The `distinct` in your source query makes me suspicious. This is often a brute force method to resolve incorrect joins or badly modelled data.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MΛIK for the tip.. Will do later.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid That's very interesting. I removed the Distinct and it resulted 800 rows instead of just 29. Im improving the SP as of now. Thank you!